# Software updates and locked EXEs/DLLs

Tags: windows, update, dll, locking

I have a question on how to best deploy/update a software package on a Windows server that is used by several users across the network.

We are in charge of updating a software package on a regular basis. This package is installed in a shared folder on machine A.

Users log into machine B via terminal client. The shared folder is accessible from machine B.

Now when we try to update the software, we often face the situation where someone is still running the software, meaning that the EXE/DLL files are locked and we cannot update them.

We cannot tell who is locking the files, since we do not have access to machine B. We basically have to call the other office every time and ask everyone to please quit the software.

What would be a saner way to implement this kind of setup? Or do we have to resort to breaking the locks?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the current network connections in `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer management > Shared folders > Sessions`.

You can also close a connection by Right clicking it and selecting "Close session", but I won't do for updating DLL's of a running program:

- [Windows Can but Won’t [replace a DLL in use]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.windowsconfidential.aspx?=blog)
- [Forcing handles closed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx)

Comment: this is exactly right.  This is a design choice to improve stability, not something you want to workaround.

Answer (score 0):

try to use unlocker (http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/)

Comment: I'm aware of this possibility, but I'd rather find a way to do this "right", instead of hacking around a design feature using a 3rd party tool. There HAS to be a better way :-)